# Modules won't allow instances of class to be made

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, class, module

I need to read more Ruby theory I have been told, which is fine but most literature I read is explained at a very high level and I don't understand it. So this leads me to the question and my code

I have a module that deals with my api call

```
module Book::BookFinder

BOOK_URL = 'https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?isbn='

def book_search(search)
response = HTTParty.get(BOOK_URL + "#{search}", :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json' })
results = JSON.parse(response.body)["results"]
end
end
```

and then my controller

```
class BookController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!
include Book::BookFinder

def results
results = book_search(params[:search])
@results = results
@book = Book.new
@book.author = results[0]["artistName"]

end

def create
@book = Book.new(params[:book])
 if @book.save
redirect_to @book, notice: 'Book was successfully saved'
 else
render action:new
end
end
end
```

What I want to do is save the author value to my Book model. I get the error message

```
undefined method `new' for Book:Module
```

when conducting a search which in a previous post has been explained to me. A module cannot be instanced. The solution was to make a class? but maybe I am not understanding correctly as I am not sure where to put this class. The solution given to me was

```
 class Book
  def initialize
   # put constructor logic here
  end

 def some_method
 # methods that can be called on the instance
 # eg:
 # @book = Book.new
 # @book.some_method
 end

# defines a get/set property
  attr_accessor :author
# allows assignment of the author property
end
```

Now I am sure that this is a valid answer, but could anyone explain what is going on? Seeing an example with an explanation is more beneficial to me than reading lines and lines of text in a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module Finders

  ## Wrap BookFinder inside another module, Finders, to better organise related
  ## code and to help avoid name collisions
  ## lib/finders/book_finder.rb
  module BookFinder
    def bar
      puts "foo"
    end
  end  
end


## Another BookFinder module, but this one is not wrapped.
## lib/book_finder.rb
module BookFinder
  def foo
    puts 'bar'
  end
end


## Book is a standard Rails model inheriting from ActiveRecord
## app/models/book.rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  ## Mixin methods from both modules
  include BookFinder
  include HelperLibs::BookFinder
end

## app/controllers/books_controller.rb
class BookController
  def create
    book = Book.new
    book.foo
    book.bar

  end
end


BookController.new.create
 - bar
 - foo
```

In your code you are creating a module and a class with the same name - this is not allowed. The module overrides the class since it is loaded second.

Comment: thank you for your answer, so by wrapping the bookfinder module in another module does this allow instances of the book class to be made?

Comment: No. You can create instances of Book because it is a class, and it is not being overridden by a module with the same name.

Comment: Im afraid i still dont understand, back to the drawing board for me i guess, thanks for trying though. I have accepted your answer though as im sure you are right

Comment: I wrapped BookFinder with another module, to demonstrate how you might go about grouping together similar classes/modules. For example when writing a ruby Gem, you should wrap your code with a module of the same name as your gem, so your modules/classes do not clash with other libraries being used by the app.

Comment: The only real problem with your code is that you have a module and a class sharing the same name, `Book`.

Comment: ok, so would you be able to show me how I would convert my code into a class so that i can create instances of it? ie create a new object for my book model? maybe then it may sink in a litte

Comment: so would changing the module name help?

Comment: Yes. And, are you familiar with Rails' rake task for generate models. e.g. `rails g model Book title:string isbn:string`

Comment: the model is already created, i am familiar with the rake task, but choose to build using migrations instead so that can rollback if needed, or is that not necessary

Comment: In that case, taking BookFinder out of the module Book, should work (assuming `book_finder.rb` is in your load path. ( `module Book::BookFinder` to `module BookFinder`

Comment: well my module is in lib/book/book_finder.rb and my lib is loaded by config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib), so no need for the folder book? also i have just changed the path to lib/api/api_call.rb and get the error uninitialized constant BookController::Book

Comment: appreciate your assistance by the way

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22186/discussion-between-osahyoun-and-richlewis)